# YouTube Data API (v3) Hosting in windows server (IIS)

Tags: c#, .net, youtube

I am using this code to upload video on youtube

[InsertVideoYoutube via .net](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#upload_a_video)

Code is working fine in my local machine but getting exception when i host my api on my IIS

Here is the exception what i am getting

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal    at BusinessClass.UploadVideo.videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged(IUploadProgress progress)     at Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload`1.<UploadAsync>d__84.MoveNext()  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()     at BusinessClass.UploadVideo.d__1.MoveNext() Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Void videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged(Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress)

Using client_secrets.json file for authorization.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: not duplicate, because in my case code is working fine in local machine, but same code not working in hosting server, may be some permission issue but not sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved the issue, I was getting unauthorize exception because in this folder

> C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Google.Apis.Auth\Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-user

There was no access for IIS Users, So i gave permission of this 'Google.Apis.Auth' folder to IIS user. And finally exception is gone, Code is working properly, Thanks for your help